# Flutter Android Can't get OAuth 2.0 verification screen to allow step data to be shared with app after selecting account; only on release build

Tags: android, flutter, google-oauth, android-manifest, google-fit

The company I'm employed at is currently working on an app built in flutter and we are using the health package from pub.dev to request permissions to and read step data from both apple health kit and google fit, respectively. IOS is working great, with no problems. However upon setting up the google oauth2 client id's in google cloud platform, we are able to get through the step data verification process in  the debug version of the app, but not in a release version of the app. We've double checked that the id we have set up for the release build has the correct package name and fingerprint, however when someone in the release build who has google fit on their phone triggers the OAuth2 request screen, and selects the google account they want to proceed with, the modal closes and the permissions status does not change. I can't tell what the issue could be since it is working fine on the debug version, but I am wondering if anyone has encountered a similar error before? Right now our app is in the verification process since health data is considered a sensitive scope to google; however upon creating the id it says that we can have 100 people approve data sharing through it before verification, so I'm not sure if it is of any consequence at the moment. Please let me know if you have any insights into this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Make sure you configured the right SHA release certificate in the GCP project. When you release your App in Play Store, the signature of the binary signed by the upload key certificate will be different than the binary distributed by Google Play. You can find the Play App Signing page under Release > Setup > App Integrity and update your GCP OAuth client accordingly. 

Note that in OAuth testing mode you can only have 100 user cap. Once you set your app status as "In production," your app will be available to anyone with a Google Account.